# fish shell,The behavior of the test command does not work

Tags: fish

I wrote the following file, but
It does not work as expected.
I have set up the test command to run if the file does not exist by using a combination of the test command option and not...

```
function touch
  /usr/bin/touch $argv
  set -l ext (echo $argv | grep -Eo "\.(.*)\$" | grep -oE '[a-zA-Z]+')
  set -l fname (echo (pwd)/$argv)
  if not test -e $fname; and test "$ext" = "xml"
      echo "detection xml format"
      cat /home/mizuiro/template/xml/template.xml >> $argv
  end
end
```

Please help me!!

Comment: If you're writing a function that wraps an external command, I'd recommend 2 things: 1) use `function touch --wraps touch` -- that enables all the completions that may exist for the touch command, and 2) use `command touch $argv` instead of hardcoding the path to the external command.

Comment: For future reference, a good question explains what "does not work" actually means. What does the code do now? How does that differ from what you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what your code is supposed to be doing, and you haven't been clear on what you want to achieve or what the error you're getting is.

Let's go through it one-by one:

> function touch

This creates a function called `touch`. While it's allowed for a function to have the same name as a well-known command like touch, it's absolutely not recommended unless it does basically the same thing (e.g. something like a `grep` function that does `grep --color=auto` is probably okay). Anywhere you run `touch` this would now try to do your special xml-handling, including in completions and functions that fish already ships. Fish functions aren't scoped or isolated in any way, making this a bad idea.

I suggest you change the name to "mytouch" or "newxml" or something.

> /usr/bin/touch $argv

This creates one or multiple files (or passes options to the `touch` program), or adjusts their atime and mtime.

```
set -l ext (echo $argv | grep -Eo "\.(.*)\$" | grep -oE '[a-zA-Z]+')
```

This presumably gets the extensions on the file you've given. If you pass multiple files, this will break because `echo` prints the arguments space-separated but the `grep` wants them one per line.

> set -l fname (echo (pwd)/$argv)

This gives the full path to the file - if you've given a relative filename. If you give an absolute filename this will print gibberish.

E.g. do `touch /tmp/foo` while you're in the directory `/home/rivi` and this will print `/home/rivi//tmp/foo`.

It will also be broken with multiple filenames. You can replace this with just

```
set -l fname $PWD/$argv
# or
set -l fname (pwd)/$argv
```

That would handle multiple arguments, although it would still be broken with absolute paths.

I also have no idea why you need the absolute path here because you've given the relative path to `touch` above.

> if not test -e $fname; and test "$ext" = "xml"

This checks two things - first it checks `not test -e $fname`, which will be true if the file doesn't exist. If that was true, it checks if the extension is "xml". If either of the tests is false, it won't go into the if-block (because of the `and`).

The first test is almost guaranteed to be false because you ran `touch` on that file. So it'll only really ever be true if you didn't have permissions to create that file or something like that.

I believe the issue is that you run `touch` before the check - which creates the file.

You might want something like

```
if not test -e "$fname"; and test "$ext" = xml
   # do your thing
else
   # not a non-existent xml file, just run touch
   /usr/bin/touch $argv
end
```

(assuming $fname makes any sense - like I said I don't see why you're using the absolute path there at all)

This also is absolutely not prepared to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: I know it is dangerous when multiple files are specified.
I am new to fish and was very suspicious.
Anyway, when generating a single file, if the file extension is "xml", I thought of adding a template to the code.
If the file already exists, there is no need to add a template, so I simply ignore it.
If this was successful, I going to support multiple files.

Comment: In that case your problem definitely is that you run `touch` before checking if the file exists, as that will create it if it doesn't.

Comment: By the way, the code you wrote does not work the way I want it to.
From what I see, I think it is with or without the double quotes, but why did you put the double quotes?
If you have a good reference, please let me know.
I have searched the documentation in my own way but can't find any good text.

Comment: Yes. I know it should have a different name. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Expanding a variable outside of double-quotes expands it to as many arguments as it has elements - if $fname had multiple elements, this might run something like `test -e foo bar`, which is nonsensical. So it's recommended to always double-quote variables when used with `test`.

Comment: You want to read fish's documentation, e.g. https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#lists

Comment: thanks for replying.
i understood how to use list concept in fish shell.
but i can't run the code showed string compare with using test command  in my environment.
is the code mistake?

Comment: I'm fairly certain my code works as intended. You'll want to look at your entire function and see where the problem lies. Is $ext empty (i.e. that grep extraction you did isn't working)? Does $fname already exist (because you forgot to remove the earlier `/usr/bin/touch`? Add `set --show fname ext` before the `if not test` bit to see what these variables are set to.